# Prove $PA^{-}\models \forall x\forall y(y\cdot x=1\to (y\neq 1\to x=1))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove $PA^{-}\models \forall x\forall y(y\cdot x=1\to (y\neq 1\to x=1))$

I don't even see how this is true. Since it seems that because PA doesn't contain multiplicative inverses that if $xy=1$ then both $x=1$ and $y=1$?

Comment: I assume PA$^-$ is the theory of discrete ordered rings?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  It's Peano Arithmetic without induction axiom.

Comment: That can mean a lot of things, and how I would take that literally (the seven or so standard axioms of PA that aren't induction), I don't think it is true. For instance, is $\forall x,y (x+y=y+x)$ an axiom (or theorem) of your system? Cause it's not a theorem of (what I would interpret as) "PA without induction". Do you have a reference that gives the axioms you are allowed to use?

Comment: For instance, is it something close to the PA$^{-}$ given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations or is it literally the 6 axioms given in the section above? The former is much stronger, though they become equivalent once you add the induction schema.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Its exactly the $PA^{-}$ given there.

Comment: Okay, I guess the notation is more standard than I thought (and I should have said *semi*-rings above). I would approach by proving the contrapositive: assume $x$ and $y$ are not equal to $1$ and prove $xy\ne 1$. Eliminate trivial case where either is zero, then show this means $x=u+1$ and $y=v+1$ where $u,v>0$ and go from there.

Comment: (Also, although the statement is suspiciously too weak, I don’t see any significant shortcuts to exploit... I think the stronger statement will just cost you a couple more cases in a case analysis. But I could be missing something.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My attempts have been to assume $yx=1$ and $y\neq 1$ and to prove $x=1$. But I have to use this false statement somehow to prove $x=1$.

Comment: You don't *have* to use it. You can just prove $x=1$ from $xy=1$. (Also, if you can establish that it's false, you're done...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove the contrapositive. In other words show that if $x\ne 1$ and $y\ne 1$ then $xy\ne 1.$ The case if $x$ or $y$ zero is easy. So assume they aren't equal to zero, so $x=u+1$ and $y=v+1$ where $u,v\ne 0.$ Then we have $$xy=(u+1)(v+1)=uv+u+v+1\ge v+1\ge 1+1>1.$$

Of course you'll need to show in some detail that all of these steps follow from the axioms. Also note that I didn't really need to assume $x$ and $y$ were both not equal to one, only that one of them was.

Comment: @Mauro That’s axiom 11. (The “point” of PA^{-} as opposed to say Robinson arithmetic, is to incorporate directly many of the straightforward facts that require quantifier-free induction to prove in the standard presentation of PA.)